# SInatra, Sequel pagination

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel

I am having problems with pagination. In addition to requiring sequel and sinatra I have:

```
require 'will_paginate'
require 'sequel/extensions/pagination'
require 'will_paginate/collection'
require 'will_paginate/sequel'
require 'will_paginate/version'
```

The query is:

```
get '/candidate' do
      @items = DB[:candidates].order(:created_at).paginate(params[:page], 10)
     erb :candidate
end
```

and the error message on candidate.erb is:

```
undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass

    file: pagination.rb
    location: paginate
    line: 19
```

What could be the problem? Is the query OK? All help gratefully received.

Comment: So which one are you using, `sequel/extensions/pagination`, or `will_paginate`? They are both pagination gems, but you should really be using one or the other to avoid conflict.

Comment: according to the guy who wrote will_paginate they do not conflict, but in any case, I have tried with and without if you see what I mean! Still struggling!